# NodeJS + sqlite3: erro ao obter informação pelo Select

Tags: node.js, sqlite3

estou aprendendo nodeJS.

Estou tentando integrá-lo ao Sqlite3, mas ao tentar ler uma informação do banco está sendo gerado o seguinte erro:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:28                                                                                          
                    throw err;                                                                                                                       
                          ^                                                                                                                          
TypeError: Cannot read property 'counter' of undefined                                                                                               
    at Statement.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:15:56)                                                                                
--> in Database#each('SELECT COUNT(id) AS counter FROM tasks', [Function])                                                                           
    at Database.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:10:10)                                                                                 
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:6:6)                                                                                     
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)                                                                                                            
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)                                                                                              
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)                                                                                                                
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)                                                                                                      
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:497:10)                                                                                             
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Segue abaixo o código do servidor:

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    var db = new sqlite3.Database("teste_db");

    db.serialize(function() {
        db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, expires INTEGER, done SMALLINT, user CHARACTER(32))");
        db.each('SELECT COUNT(id) AS counter FROM tasks', function(err, rows){
                if (err) {
                    callback(err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log("contagem de linhas: " + rows[0].counter);
            });
        });
    db.close();
```

Não importa qual nome eu dê para o campo a ser lido no banco, ele sempre presume que o nome do campo seja uma propriedade do array ROWS.

OBS: no exemplo usei um COUNT, mas em qualquer tipo de select ele retorna esse erro

Alguém pode me dizer onde estou errando?

Comment: pode logar o objeto rows e postar aqui? pode ser quye a tabela não tenha sido criada, pela natureza assíncrona do nodejs

Comment: Outra coisa, existe um ORM bem leve e simples para node, com uma documentação ótima. Chama-se Sequelize, recomendo dar uma olhada qualquer hora. Facilita bem o trabalho

Answer (score 1):

A função de grupo COUNT não retorna um array. Se você inspecionar o retorno você vai verificar o seguinte JSON: `{ counter: 0 }`.
Portanto, modifique a linha onde você imprime a contagem de linhas para

```js
console.log("contagem de linhas: " + rows.counter);
```

e tudo vai funcionar corretamente.

P.S.: como na verdade não retornam vários registros, sugiro mudar `rows` para `row`, `result` ou algo mais apropriado.